# Problema com timeout em asp classico

Tags: asp, timeout

Estou com um problema que após um usuário normal visualizar o comparativo no gráfico que precisa, após passar alguns minutos se ele clicar novamente no botão "OK" sem ter mexido em nada antes, ele consegue visualizar o nome das empresas no gráfico, sendo que estes nomes tem que ser vistos apenas como "Empresa A", "Empresa B". 
Como deslogar ao clicar novamente em algo na página após passar um tempo ?

Comment: Você está usando sessão no seu sistema de login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma variável de Sessão no global.asa e teste-a toda vez que uma página for recarregada, caso este botão seja um redirecionamento de página.

ex:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript RUNAT=Server>
Option Explicit
Sub Session_OnStart 
    SESSION("LOGON") =true
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

Página:
    if SESSION("LOGON") = false then
       response.redirect "paginadedesvio.html"
    end if

Se não for um redirecionamento de página, você terá que testá-la através de ajax e redirecionar a página dependendo da resposta dela

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar arquitetar a geração desse gráfico usando tabelas consolidadas. Isso evitaria ficar calculando toda vez que precisar gerá-lo.

Você pode estipular um "timeout" para seu script:

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 300 '5 minutos.
```